# SELECT MIN Date(using WINDOW function) and MAX Date(with related field using JOIN) together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Table T1

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+
| ID |   Sdate    |   Edate    | Reason | Type |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+
|  1 | 5/30/2016  |            |        | A    |
|  1 | 1/19/2016  | 12/15/2016 | USD    | B    |
|  1 | 11/20/2016 | 10/1/2016  | IT     | B    |
|  2 | 10/25/2016 |            |        | A    |
|  2 | 9/22/2016  | 7/11/2016  | SD     | B    |
|  2 | 2/13/2016  |            |        | A    |
|  2 | 1/1/2016   | 4/3/2016   | IT     | B    |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+
```

For each ID, I need to select the minimum Sdate for Type=A and maximum Edate for Type=B, alongwith the Discharge Reason associated with Type=B. There are more than just two types but I've shown A and B as an example

**Desired Output:**

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
| Customer ID | Startdate |  Enddate   | Discharge Reason |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|           1 | 5/30/2016 | 12/15/2016 | USD              |
|           2 | 2/13/2016 | 7/11/2016  | SD               |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
```

Attempt:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    ID
    ,SDate
    ,EDate
    ,Reason
    ,Type
FROM T1
)

SELECT
     CTE.ID AS [Customer ID]
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Type='A' THEN CTE.SDate END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.CID) AS StartDate
    ,CTE.EDate AS Enddate
    ,CTE.Reason AS [Discharge Reason]

FROM CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT CTE.ID, MAX(CTE.EDate) AS EEDate 
FROM CTE WHERE CTE.Type='B' GROUP BY CTE.ID) CTE2
    ON CTE.ID=CTE2.ID AND CTE.Edate=CTE2.EEDAte
```

This gives me a blank Startdate column since the INNER JOIN on outer co-related subquery which is used to get the Max `Edate` and the associated `Discharge Reason`, causes the query to ignore `Type=A` and hence no Startdates. How do I make these work together?

Comment: please edit your question to include that **critical detail** "*In the original table, the types are a lot more...*" in *Vladimer's* answer. Because in your question you specifically mention Type=[A, B] as though those are the only options.

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic `top-n-per-group` problem, which you need to do twice.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Sdate date, Edate date, Reason varchar(50), Type char(1));
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Sdate, Edate, Reason, Type) VALUES
(1, '2016-05-30', NULL         , NULL , 'A'),
(1, '2016-01-19', '2016-12-15' , 'USD', 'B'),
(1, '2016-11-20', '2016-10-01' , 'IT' , 'B'),
(2, '2016-10-25', NULL         , NULL , 'A'),
(2, '2016-09-22', '2016-07-11' , 'SD' , 'B'),
(2, '2016-02-13', NULL         , NULL , 'A'),
(2, '2016-01-01', '2016-04-03' , 'IT' , 'B');
```

Number the rows twice.

`PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type, Sdate` will give row number 1 for each `ID` and smallest `Sdate` and `Type=A`.

`PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type DESC, Edate DESC` will give row number 1 for each `ID` and largest `Edate` and `Type=B`.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,Sdate
    ,Edate
    ,Reason
    ,Type
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type, Sdate) AS rnA
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type DESC, Edate DESC) AS rnB
FROM @T
ORDER BY ID, Type, Sdate
;
```

**Intermediate result**

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+-----+-----+
| ID |   Sdate    |   Edate    | Reason | Type | rnA | rnB |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+-----+-----+
|  1 | 2016-05-30 | NULL       | NULL   | A    |   1 |   3 |
|  1 | 2016-01-19 | 2016-12-15 | USD    | B    |   2 |   1 |
|  1 | 2016-11-20 | 2016-10-01 | IT     | B    |   3 |   2 |
|  2 | 2016-02-13 | NULL       | NULL   | A    |   1 |   3 |
|  2 | 2016-10-25 | NULL       | NULL   | A    |   2 |   4 |
|  2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-04-03 | IT     | B    |   3 |   2 |
|  2 | 2016-09-22 | 2016-07-11 | SD     | B    |   4 |   1 |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------+-----+-----+
```

Now we need to get rows with `rnA=1` and `rnB=1` and put them together joining by `ID`.

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Sdate
        ,Edate
        ,Reason
        ,Type
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type, Sdate) AS rnA
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type DESC, Edate DESC) AS rnB
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_A
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Sdate
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rnA = 1
)
,CTE_B
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Edate
        ,Reason
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rnB = 1
)
SELECT
    CTE_A.ID
    ,CTE_A.Sdate
    ,CTE_B.Edate
    ,CTE_B.Reason
FROM
    CTE_A
    INNER JOIN CTE_B ON CTE_B.ID = CTE_A.ID
ORDER BY ID
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+
| ID |   Sdate    |   Edate    | Reason |
+----+------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2016-05-30 | 2016-12-15 | USD    |
|  2 | 2016-02-13 | 2016-07-11 | SD     |
+----+------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you think there could be an alternate way to choose Type=A or B besides ordering alphabetically and determining the row number? In the original table, the types are a lot more, are more complex and dynamic. Or would I have to reluctantly hard-code the Type in filters for row numbers to work?

Comment: @AS91, it depends on how complex the logic behind the `Type` is. In the end you need to be able to separate rows with type `A` from `B`. The query above cuts some corners by calculating two sets of row numbers in one `SELECT`. If it is more complicated, have two `SELECTs` with proper filters that leave only `A` or `B` rows. And in the end join results by `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT
    t.ID
    ,t.SDate
    ,t.EDate
    ,Reason
FROM (
SELECT  ID, MIN(CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN SDate END) as SDate , max(CASE WHEN Type='B' THEN EDate END ) as EDate
FROM T1
group by ID) t 
INNER JOIN T1 on t.ID = T1.id and t.EDate = T1.Edate and type = 'B'
```

OR

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  ID, MIN(CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN SDate END) as SDate , max(CASE WHEN Type='B' THEN EDate END ) as EDate
FROM T1
group by ID
)
SELECT
     CTE.ID AS [Customer ID]
    ,CTE.SDate AS StartDate
    ,CTE.EDate AS Enddate
    ,T1.Reason AS [Discharge Reason]

FROM CTE
INNER JOIN T1 
    ON CTE.ID=T1.ID AND CTE.Edate=T1.EDAte and T1.type = 'B'
```

provided there are no duplicate max dates to type B. if there are, you will need to tweak it a bit.